# Need help identifying some shrubs in the mountains of Israel

Tags: identification, shrubs

I see some bushes around my house and am wondering whether they are useful (if so, I will propagate them from cuttings.) Can anyone identify these?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you ask one question per plant, please? And ideally include also a close-up as well? Any additional information (e.g. scent) would be helpful and of course the location (saves users from digging through your profile).

Comment: Ooh, that's a landscape I haven't seen in a few years. Thanks for the photos :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in the mountains of Crete!

- The first one could be sage, to be more precise [salvia triloba](http://quickbooker.org/kunden/wildherbsofcrete_com/pages/portraits-of-our-essential-oils-from-wild-herbs-of-crete/salvia-triloba.php). Need a close-up to verify.
- The second one is surely thyme.
- The last one, I don´t know.

If you tell a little bit more about smell and make some close-ups as suggested, we may be able to help some more.